# Polynomial "LinEst" VBA-call using array instead of range

Tags: excel, vba, regression, interpolation

I am not able to retrieve the coefficients for a second order linest function and the MsgBox returns an error : "Type mismatch".

I expect the linest function to give {0,0,1} as I used the square function f:x->x² for this example.

```
Sub RunLinestOld()
Dim vectorX() As Double
Dim vectorY() As Double
Dim theLeastSquareCoef


'redimensionne les vecteurs
ReDim vectorX(1 To 4)
ReDim vectorY(1 To 4)

vectorX(1) = 1
vectorX(2) = 2
vectorX(3) = 3
vectorX(4) = 4

vectorY(1) = 1
vectorY(2) = 4
vectorY(3) = 9
vectorY(4) = 16


'theLeastSquareCoef = Application.LinEst(vectorY, vectorX)
theLeastSquareCoef = Application.LinEst(vectorY, Application.Power(vectorX, Array(1, 2)))

**MsgBox "K is " & Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 1, 2)**

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this with the below code. You need to pass matrix of dimension Nx1 to the LinEst function, and NOT a vector.

```
Sub RunLinEst()
    Dim vectorX() As Double
    Dim vectorY() As Double
    Dim theLeastSquareCoef


    'you need to define matrix otherwise it doesn't work
    ReDim vectorX(0 To 4, 0 To 0)
    ReDim vectorY(0 To 4, 0 To 0)

    vectorX(0, 0) = 0
    vectorX(1, 0) = 1
    vectorX(2, 0) = 2
    vectorX(3, 0) = 3
    vectorX(4, 0) = 4

    vectorY(0, 0) = 0
    vectorY(1, 0) = 1
    vectorY(2, 0) = 4
    vectorY(3, 0) = 9
    vectorY(4, 0) = 16


    theLeastSquareCoef = Application.LinEst(vectorY, Application.Power(vectorX, Array(1, 2))) 

    Range("F4").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 1)
    Range("F5").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 2)
    Range("F6").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 3)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of linest to string

```
 MsgBox("K is " & CStr(Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 1, 2)))
```

Comment: I found the following info (scroll about halfway down for answer) and used your data in cells. I got an answer, but no idea if it is correct  :(  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/problem-using-linest-in-vba/a25caa50-2492-45d5-9fdb-4547c4b1a4c7

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately I got "K is Error 2015" as output instead of a number close to zero.